# Remover conectores de String com Expressao Regular

Tags: java, regex

Como eu poderia remover conectores: "e", "do", "da", "do", "das", "de", "di", "du". De uma frase sem alterar todo o nome.

Exemplo o nome: Daniela de Andrade. Eu queria remover apenas "de", sem remover o "DA"niela de andra"DE" eu estou utilizando a funcao relaceAll no java.

```
    String retiraConector = "^\\s e $\\s";

   nome = nome.replaceAll(retiraConector, " ");
```

Comment: Conforme você viu no [tour], se achar que o objetivo principal desta pergunta foi alcançado, você pode aceitar uma resposta. Também poderá votar em tudo no site que achar útil, não só nas coisas ligadas aos seus posts.

Answer (score 9):

Você pode utilizar o seguinte padrão:

```
String padrao = "(\\w)(\\s+)(e|do|da|do|das|de|di|du)(\\s+)(\\w)";
```

Esse padrão foi dividido em cinco grupos, estes seguem a ordem:

*qualquer letra ou número* **+** *um ou mais espaços* **+** *conector* **+** *um ou mais espaços* **+** *qualquer letra ou número*

*Nota: os grupos são formados através do parenteses.*

Para fazer a substituição utilize:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String padrao = "(\\w)(\\s+)(e|do|da|do|das|de|di|du)(\\s+)(\\w)";
    String nome = "Daniela de Andrade";
    System.out.println(nome.replaceAll(padrao, "$1 $5"));
}
```

O resultado é o seguinte:

`Daniela Andrade`

Quando você utiliza o `replaceAll`, o padrão é encontrado em `Daniel[a de A]ndrade`, e é substituído pelos grupos 1 e 5, que são separandos por um espaço em branco, esses grupos são representados pelo **a**, de Daniel**a**, e o **A**, de **A**ndrade.

---

**Revisão**

Para ignorar letras maiúsculas e minúsculas, você pode usar `(?i)` na sua expressão, por exemplo:

```
String padrao = "(?i)(\\w)(\\s+)(e|do|da|do|das|de|di|du)(\\s+)(\\w)";
```

A maneira de se realizar a substituição é a mesma informada acima.

Comment: Opa, Obrigado, resolveu o meu problema, eu acrescentei [dD][eE] para recuperar maiusculo e minusculo.

Comment: @Gabriel se resolveu, não se esqueça de aceitar a resposta. Veja em[tour].

Comment: @GabrielFaria melhorei minha resposta para contemplar também esse tipo de verificação.

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo a resposta do @Mateus Alexandre:

Você pode utilizar o seguinte padrão também:

```
String padrao = "\s(e|d(a|e|i|o|u)s?)\s";
```

Esse padrão foi dividido em dois grupos, estes seguem a ordem:

*espaço* **+** *conector* **+** *espaço*

apenas alterando:

```
System.out.println(nome.replaceAll(padrao, "$1 $5"));
```

para

```
System.out.println(nome.replaceAll(padrao, " "));
```

Comment: creio que está faltando uma barra na expressão (`\s` para `\\s`), não?

Comment: @MateusAlexandre, na verdade não ha necessidade, em expressão regular `\s` é um `meta sequence` (um atalho), alguns programadores utilizam `\\s`, mas não sei lhe explicar a razão exata, pela logica poderia ser uma tentativa de interpretação literal. exemplo `\\W` que poderia capturar o `$` que é um carácter especial de fim, desta forma interpretando literalmente `\$`, contudo no `\\w`, poderia capturar um `t`, ficando `\t`, que também é um `meta sequence`.
Para testes recomendo o site : http://regex101.com/

Comment: Em um pesquisa rápida encontrei isto:
"Em uma expressão regular definida com o construtor new, para usar uma metassequência que comece com o caractere de barra invertida (\) , como \d (que corresponde a qualquer dígito), digite duas vezes esse caractere de barra invertida:"
`var pattern:RegExp = new RegExp("\\d+", "");`, ou seja o `\\` na verdade esta sendo usado para interpretação da string como `\`, ficando `\d`.

Comment: sim, exatamente, eu disse isso porque testei no NetBeans e Eclipse e ambos acusaram como sequência de escape inválida